# Purge local maven repo of all SNAPSHOT dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I am in an environment where multiple versions of a jar file with the same name can be published to a local Nexus installation. These jar files are always named XYZ-SNAPSHOT.jar. Our continuous integration system needs to always pull the latest version, so our automated build currently contains the following to wipe out the complete local repo on the Continuous Integration machine:

> mvn dependency:purge-local-repository

This forces *all* dependencies to be downloaded on each build, which makes it take a very long time. Is there some way to use the 'includes' flag with a wildcard. Something that I would assume looks like this:

> mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -includes="*-SNAPSHOT.jar"

It would also be acceptable to add a new mvn target if that has the necessary flexibility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Yes there is this flexibility available to filter dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html#includes)  also to [specify just SNAPSHOTS](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html#snapshotsOnly)

try

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DmanualInclude="com.abc:artifact-id" -DsnapshotsOnly=true
```

Comment: ideally you should be dependent on releases if something you are consuming is changing frequently and which is out of your maven pom tree, @kdg true story

Comment: Neither 'includes' nor 'include' worked for me ('includes' looks like it is for use in pom.xml only, not CLI). Using 'manualInclude' did work, however.

Comment: @Peter ok thank you, I updated answer with that option

Comment: Can someone else verify that this actually works on an artifact that has *both* releases and snapshots in the local repository? I've tried all the various combinations of the goal's parameters and it still purges all versions and not just the snapshots.

Comment: Ah, so this isn't terribly clear from the documentation, but the `snapshotsOnly` parameter is a "let me purge depedencies... but wait, lets only look at the ones that are currently at a snapshot version", and NOT a "let me go purge all the dependencies, but only purge the snapshots". It's an important distinction.